# stop a link if user isn't logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you please help me? This one seems simple but none of my solutions work.

I have a table of pdf links on a page. I want user be able to open them only and only if he is logged in. otherwise an alert message pops up.

If we consider each link is inside a div like below:

```
<div class="prdc prdc-prodList noAccess">
   <a target="_blank" href="/files/test.pdf">Specification</a>
</div>
```

If user isn't logged in, "noAccess" class is assigned to the link parent otherwise "hasAccess" is assigned to it.

I have this code, but (in case user is logged out) it doesn't work all the times.

```
$( ".prdc a" ).click(function(e) {

    if ( $( this ).parent().hasClass( "noAccess" ) ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("You should be logged in to have access");
    }

});
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with this code? Or do you know a better solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: this is a terrible idea actually, you need to control it in server side, with editing html, somebody can easily access to the content you try to prevent from being seen.

Comment: @Burak Do you mean I should change the generated HTML from server side? That's right. I was thinking about that too but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I agree with Burak. This should be handled on server side. The moment you send information to the client, they have it whether you decide to fobid access or not.

@Fateme - the first question is, how is your HTML generated? Are you using PHP? If so then you should looking into $_SESSION[] variables.

Comment: @FatemeNaderpour not generating html, you should just check the sessions in the server side, if there is a valid session, you can let the user see that file, if not then you need to redirect the user so that user can't see the file.

Comment: I changed it in server side. now it's working very well :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all - this is not a good way to do this.
This is because some users who know how to handle developer tools might just delete the class noAccess and access your files. Therefore you should either:
1. Not display the links at all if the user is not logged in.
2. Add additional check on the server side for the status of logged in user and prevent download if the user is not logged in.

And answering your question:

This is probably coused by the use of `parent()` function. It only gets direct parent of an object, and what you want is `closest('.noAccess')`. This function will look all predecesors of a given object which have class `noAcess`.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

do this by first not puting the `href` in `a` and then when the user has loged in then by using javascript add `href`. The following code illustrates this:

```
<div class="prdc prdc-prodList noAccess">
   <a target="_blank" id="link">Specification</a></div>
```

**javascript**

```
var some_function_name = function(){
  if( some conditions if the user has loged in or not ){
    var a = document.getElementById("link");
        a.setAttriblue("href","/files/test.pdf");
 }
}
```

and after the user has loged in the your html will look like this:

```
<div class="prdc prdc-prodList noAccess">
       <a target="_blank" id="link" href="/files/test.pdf">Specification</a></div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yxrqn/)